# Syncronize vertical list using tags and connections

Tags: lists, tags, card-sorting

My goal is to create a three vertical lists where user can filter them using tags and a search bar, move elements between them using drag and drop (similar to trello) and display explicit connections using lines.

Here a quick mockup of my idea:

[image]

My questions are:

- search bar with a lot of tags are a mess or could be simplified with groups between tags ?
- are card the right choice for display a quick summary (title, ref image), some actions for elements or is better to have a more simplified element with less data, because of connections between them ?
- because lists can have more elements than 3, so scrollbars involved, what if a line connect a card on bottom to one on the top ? I think will be a mess soon
- there are similar interfaces around ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I don't think you'll need to worry about too many tags. If the user is putting in a bunch of tags, then I don't think they're using the feature correctly. The majority would want to use a few to target the elements that they want.
- Depends on the number of elements you're expecting in each column, having a smaller "card" could definitely help, if the ref-image is important, then maybe a UI for "quick view" on click/hover could help, something like what [JIRA](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/0*d72j3xcQJB7rjp1V.) is doing.
- Yes this could get messy, maybe don't show the connections by default, create a UI element to show connections specifically for a particular card, and change the columns to only show related cards.
- You can look at JIRA's interface or look at some images of kanban boards to get some inspiration.

Comment: Thanks! Quick view on select is a nice touch, thanks for remind me about this solution! Also with connection will be for sure messy, I wonder if is possible to mix kanban with mindmap, there connection are easily displayed using connections, with zoom out

Answer (score 1):

My main concern is that every column can have a scroll bar and the connections between the cards can be quite messy.
You need to test this with more items to verify it scales.

Trello is also a good option(and free) to view some good example of similar view.
another option is to have a button displaying and hiding the connections.  in the display connections mode, you filter to view only the connected ones.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that another test is useful and "connection mode" will provide right context when user select a card